# Yii2 hiddenInput does not react on options value

Tags: yii2, active-form

Going to change image field in model by changing value in hidden field:

View:

```
<?= HTML::activeHiddenInput($model, 'image_clean', [
    'id' => 'cleaner',
    'name' => 'cleaner',
    'value' => false
])
?>
<?=
Html::button('Remove logo', [
    'id' => 'btn_clean',
])
?>
```

at the end of view:

```
    <?php
    $this->registerJs(<<<JS
    $('#btn_clean').on('click', function() {
        alert('Going to remove logo'); // Reachable!
        $('#cleaner').val(true);
    });
JS
    );
    ?>
```

Model:

```
public $image_clean;    // Remove logo

public function rules() {
    return [
        //...
        [['image_clean'], 'boolean'],
        //...
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels() {
    return [
        //...
        'image_clean' => 'Remove logo',
        //...
    ];
}

public function beforeValidate() {
    if($this->image_clean) { }  // Never!
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}

public function beforeSave($insert) {
    if($this->image_clean) { } // Never!
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Unfortunately, $this->image_clean in model's beforeValidate / beforeSave always false. Why?

Javascript btn_clean handler works as it should be.

Comment: You should use `0` and `1` - not `true` or `false`.

Comment: Doesn't matter which value and which type returned (returned?) by hiddeninput - it has no impact on model image_clean value

Comment: You should set initial value for this like `$model->image_clean = 0;` for example in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Hiddeninput's name overrides default one.
So, I just remove 'name' => 'cleaner'. It's not required